# Difference Blending Option

Tags: after-effects

I saw this cool effect that blends bubbles into each other, and the space that they are overlapping is transparent.
[image]

How can I achieve this effect in after effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in blending mode "Difference"

You can use it in "Blending mode" of layer, or on masks.

**UPD:** Adding screenshot, as asked
[image]

Red — Mask Blending

Blue — Layer Blending

Comment: Do you mind taking on screenshot on how?

Comment: Screenshot added to the original answer.